# Twitter bootstrap icon not visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Using twitter bootstrap i have designed these two pages and wierd thing is the icons are visible only one page and not on other..

https://music-cloud.ap01.aws.af.cm/index.html

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>&nbsp;Home</a></li>
  <li ><a href="login.html"><i class="icon-signin"></i>&nbsp;Login</a></li>
  <li ><a href="register.html"><i class="icon-group"></i>&nbsp;Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

https://music-cloud.ap01.aws.af.cm/login.html

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li ><a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i>&nbsp;Home</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-signin"></i>&nbsp;Login</a></li>
  <li ><a href="register.html"><i class="icon-group"></i>&nbsp;Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the icons are FontAwesome...

Answer (score 1):

you missed this css file..`font-awesome.css`

icon styles are defined in font-awesome.css

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, looking at the source for both pages, only one contains the reference to [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/):

```
  <link rel=StyleSheet href="css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" media=all>
```

Which is: https://music-cloud.ap01.aws.af.cm/login.html

Using a common header file and using absolute URLs would help make sure no required includes are missed off or break if you move content or directories:

```
  <link rel=StyleSheet href="/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" media=all>
                             ^
```